# Android calculator buttons

Tags: android, button, android-button

I am trying to make a calculator for Android. Here is the code for my buttons:

```
int[] button_ids = {
    R.id.BtnNum0, R.id.BtnNum1, R.id.BtnNum2, R.id.BtnNum3, R.id.BtnNum4, R.id.BtnNum5, R.id.BtnNum6,
    R.id.BtnNum7, R.id.BtnNum8, R.id.BtnNum9, R.id.BtnAdd, R.id.BtnSub, R.id.BtnDiv, R.id.BtnMult,
    R.id.BtnClear, R.id.equals
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditTextValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    TVValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);      
    buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

    for(int id : button_ids) {
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(id);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttons.add(button);
    }   

}
```

How I can change this part to a block of code where I won't have to declare the IDs of the buttons? (e.g. `R.id.BtnNum0`)

```
int[] button_ids = {
    R.id.BtnNum0, R.id.BtnNum1, R.id.BtnNum2, R.id.BtnNum3, R.id.BtnNum4, R.id.BtnNum5, R.id.BtnNum6,
    R.id.BtnNum7, R.id.BtnNum8, R.id.BtnNum9, R.id.BtnAdd, R.id.BtnSub, R.id.BtnDiv, R.id.BtnMult,
    R.id.BtnClear, R.id.equals
};
```

I have been searching for an answer, but I still can't find a solution.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. First of all, the values for the R.id variables will be generated by the compiler and you will need to access them by the id value only.

Comment: I actually think this is a pretty good way to deal with this problem. You have no code duplication and make explicit for which buttons the `onClickListener` should be used.

Comment: If you really do not want to declare all the button ID's like that you can always just create the buttons programmatically in a loop instead of in your XML.

Comment: Completely agree with @silverback . This seems to be the best solution for this one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, since this code seems to only set a single `OnClickListener` for all `Button`s, is to do it in xml

For each `Button` set

```
android:onClick="functionName"
```

then in your code you can do away with all of the `id's` and your `for loop`. In Java just create a function like

```
public void functionName(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.buttonId:
        // do work for this Button
         break;
       ...
}
```

The way you are doing it is fine but this is how I prefer to handle this situation. You just have to give all of the `Buttons` the same function name in xml then use that name as your function name in Java. You also just have to be sure to declare the function with a `void` return type and make sure it takes a `View` as its one and only parameter as in my example.

[The Button Docs also have an example of this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: Hi. I have a follow up question regarding this code. Can I have a substitute code for the cases, so instead of using "R.id.buttonId" per button, a block of code that will identify which button was pressed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. That's how you identify which was pressed. `v.getId()` is getting the `id` of the `Button` that was pressed

Answer (score 1):

in your layout file add this to every button

```
 <Button
   ...
   android:onClick="btnClicked"
   .../>
```

then in your code add this method and check for each button in this method

```
public void btnClicked(View v)
{
   switch(v.getId())
   {
      case R.id.BtnNum0:
      // your code
      break;
      ....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is likely the best solution unfortunately, unless you use some sort of annotation framework which still doesn't cut down much on the boilerplate.

**edit:**

You could try to get a pointer to whatever ViewGroup is holding the Button views and then getting all of its children, and then looping through them while casting them to Buttons as you go.

For example: If your Button objects in XML are housed in a LinearLayout, you could get the pointer to that and do something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < ((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
    Button nextChild = (Button) ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
}
```

Of course, I recommend against this, but it is still a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

As trevor-e suggested, you can give an annotation processor a try. [Android Annotations](http://androidannotations.org/) can simplify your code to:

```
@Click
public void BtnNum0() {
    // Button 0 clicked
}
@Click
public void BtnNum1() {
    // Button 1 clicked
}
// etc.
```

If you go this route, please do try to use names following the Java convention as the button names correspond with function names.